# SqlCommand don't throw error for cast e

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I have a system that runs on SQL Server 2008. I don’t get any exception when I execute some query from a .NET application.

This is an example, I run the following statement. I'm attempting to get the server to throw an exception:

```
myQueryStringVar = "select cast('test' as bit)"
Dim mySqlCmd As New SqlCommand(myQueryStringVar, Connection)
```

But executing command I don't get any exception.

If I try this query on Enterprise Manager, but on different system (I've not access to Enterprise Manager on that machine) I get following error:

```
  select cast('test' as bit)
```

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'test' to data type bit.

I'd kindly like to know if someone can provide some input for future investigation.

Do you know if it's possible to set threshold exception level on SQL Server? So if error if less important that exception level I don’t get exception.

Thank you
Maurizio

Comment: Are you sure no exception gets thrown? what is your SQL schema?

Comment: Provide a complete example: [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: SQL Server errors with a severity of 11 and higher will raise an exception to the client.  This conversion error is severity 16 so you should get an exception. If you do not see the exception, perhaps there is an issue with the exception handling code.